# In Jquery mobile for tablet selectors do not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tablet

I would like to understand what is wrong with or what is the right syntax to write.
I use jquery 1.11.3 and jqueryMobile 1.4.5 and as tablet a kindle fire with browser firefox and an ipod with browser safari

Instead of document ready, I read that I need to use another kind of syntax because of jquery mobile way of dealing with pages.

With this code there is no alert triggered on tablets, but it works perfectly on the browser on my pc

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#main-page", function(){
    alert("test= " + $('.media').length)
}
```

Anything that I try to do with the $ doesn't work and show the page like it isn't finished loaded and no alert is shown.

If I check if jquery is working, it shows me that it is not loaded (but it doesn't make any sense to me because $(document) it is jquery!!!).

I have no idea what to do and how to debug, or what I can do.

Comment: `alert(typeof jQuery);` if that's `undefined`, the problem is jQuery isn't loaded. past that there isn't much we can do to help you with such a small amount of information.

Comment: Tell me what you need to know. The result of that alert is "function"

Comment: That would mean jQuery is in fact defined. I don't know what else to debug for past that unfortunately, haven't used jq mobile in years. I'd have to have the app in my hands.

Comment: I am sorry kevin you were right, I made for a mistake the test on the browser and not on the tablet. For some reason the when i check the type of on the tablet it gives me a different result Undefined. I am suspicious that because I am connecting to the website through the IP of my computer through wifi that it could be the problem

Comment: Are you linking to a local copy of jQuery, or an external cdn

Comment: @KevinB looking for a local copy. I made a test to see if it would work as external link and nothing changed. I am not understanding why Jquery wouldn't be loaded, is it too early in the rendering of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! it was all fault of Phalcon debugbar. On the mobile devices was generating an error that it wasn't happening on the normal browser. This error was making any jquery or selectors working.

Thank you for your help and support!